Doxygen "no matching class member" when using alias of template specialization
I'm new to using doxygen and can't figure out why I'm getting warnings in my project, which contain some weird templates/aliases. For info I just downloaded the most recent version 1.12.0 and still have this issue.
Here is a minimal example:
struct A
{
    void f(); // Declaration of A::f
};

template<class T>
struct B
{
    using BA = A; // Alias A
};

struct C : B<int> {};

void C::BA::f() {} // Definition of A::f via alias in template specialization base

This code gives the warning

file.cpp:14: warning: no matching class member found for
void C::BA::f()Possible candidates:
'void A::f()' at line 3 of file file.cpp

Since this is valid C++ I would expect doxygen to find that C::BA is just another name for A, but apparently not. What is stranger to me is that if I declare the struct C in a slightly different way I get no warnings anymore:
using Bint = B<int>;

struct C : Bint {};

Is there something I'm missing or is this just a bug?

Doxygen is not a C++ compiler. It finds names mostly by comparing names textually. It does know a few scopes where names can be found, but it does not do a full-blown C++-like name lookup.

Don't be too smart. In the shown case, the name of the function is A::f, not C::BA::f.

This is just a minimal example that shows my issue. Problem is, in the real project, A is a templated type that hides many details, and only the function f has to be implemented from outside. Accessing the type via A is very ugly and confusing, but via the alias C::BA it becomes understandable.

And I feel like using an alias for B should not change the way doxygen finds things. using-declarations are very common and should not affect doxygen-generation in my mind.
